# Python search a match in a list considering all words lowercase

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary

I need to search for a match of a word in python list. I must first convert both the word and all the words in the list to lowercase

```
def check_match(word,words_dict):
    for w in words_dict:
        if(word.lower()==w.lower()):
            return 1
    return 0
```

Comment: Why not use `in` operand? and whats your question?

Comment: `if word.lower()==w.lower():`

Comment: Also, note that Python has booleans, why `return 1` not `return True`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def check_match(word, words_dict):
    word_lower = word.lower()
    for w in words_dict:
        if word_lower == w.lower():
            return 1
    return 0
```

This is about as good as it's going to get. You don't want to map the `lower` operation to everything in `words_dict` because you might be able to determine a match earlier and exit the loop, doing less work.

For example, imagine if you matched the first element of `words_dict`: you wouldn't want to have wasted time forming up something like `[w.lower() for w in words_dict]` *just so* you can use `in` to express the condition you're looking for.

The only tweak I really made was precomputing `word.lower()` once so you don't do it on every pass of the loop.

Note also it's misleading in Python to name something `words_dict` when it is actually intended to be a `list`. Why not just call it `words`?

Answer (score 0):

A pythonistic way:

```
def check_match(word, words_list):    
   return any( i for i in words_list if i.lower() == word.lower() )
```

To return your bizarre `1` or `0` :

```
def check_match(word, words_list):    
   found = any( i for i in words_list if i.lower() == word.lower() )
   return 1 if found else 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want something nice looking and really don't care about performance you could try:

```
def check_match(word, words_dict):
    return word.lower in [w.lower for w in words_dict]
```

or:

```
def check_match(word, words_dict):
    return word.lower in map(lower, words_dict)
```

You can do `return int(...)` or `int(check_match(...))` (when calling the function) if the 1 and 0 are important.